# Как мне сделать скринкасты для запросов на разрешения использования технологий Instagram API, если то, как именно их нужно сделать, - звучит абсурдно?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api, instagram-api, facebooksdk, facebook-graph-api

В данный момент я разрабатываю клиентское приложение, которое должно иметь механизм "Поиск по хештегам". По документации про Graph API я понял, что мне нужно отправить запросы на разрешения использования таких технологий, как instagram_basic, pages_read_engagement и Instagram Public Content Access, при этом в запросах нужно рассказать и **показать**, как я буду использовать каждую из этих технологий. Так вот в чём абсурд: я запрашиваю разрешения на использование технологий, которыми я пользуюсь на скринкасте, показывая, как я это использую. Отсюда вопрос: если я не могу использовать эти технологии, но на видео надо показать, что я их использую, то как сделать скринкаст? Мантаж Ультиматуум?